# Error when testing app from mobile device - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, osx-yosemite

After upgrading to OSX Yosemite, I can no longer test my app on a mobile device by using my development machine's (MacBook Pro) IP address.  For example, I used to be able to view a Rails app on a phone by going to http://192.168.0.4:3000, but now I get the following error:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I get the same error when testing an AngularJS app using the grunt server running at http://192.168.0.4:9000

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your ip or firewall, maybe it will help

Comment: Just checked my firewall settings under System Preferences > Security & Privacy and it is turned off.  Could there be another one installed on a Mac by default?  Thanks.

Comment: have you reinstalled all your libraries?

Comment: I've re-installed all my node/npm libraries, but not my ruby libraries.  But I get the same error message using a ruby server or a node one.

Comment: As Alex said, have you checked your IP address? If your network setup is like most peoples, you get yours assigned via DHCP, meaning it can change. Type `ifconfig` in Terminal and look for the 'inet' entry in either en0 or en1.

Comment: Just checked that.  The 'inet' entry is what I expect.  Same as under System Preferences > Network.

Comment: did turning off IPv6 work?

Comment: No, this did not work either.  I wish I hadn't upgraded to Yosemite.  It has been a pain.

Answer (score 10):

It could help to bind the server to your local IP, like

```
rails s -p9000 -b192.168.0.4
```

to start your rails app

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. I had the same issue, except I was using port 3000 so for me it was just rails s -bMY LAN IP.

Answer (score 1):

Consider giving a try to [Pow](http://pow.cx/). Its pretty simple to install, and a great solution to share a local development across multiple devices.

Like it explains in their homepage, you can install it with just :
`curl get.pow.cx | sh`. To prevent any errors, install in Terminal app outside a Tmux session.

And just symlink your app :

```
 cd ~/.pow
 ln -s /path/to/myapp
```

You can access your app at http://myapp.dev/, and at `http://myapp.[your ip address].xip.io` from another device.

Not a direct response to your issue, but an alternative to setting yourself a configuration in your preferences.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I develop my AngularJS front-end separately with yeoman, bower, and grunt.  These tools use a node-based web server so I do not think this will solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Turn IPv6 off**. It Prevented me from connecting to my localhost from other computers on my LAN. And, with the newer versions of OSX there is no way to turn it off in the Network Preferences Panel so you have to do it from terminal.

Open Terminal and enter to turn it off:

```
networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi
```

And this to turn it back on:

```
networksetup -setv6LinkLocal Wi-Fi
```

---

If you are connected via Ethernet or something else just run this command to list the available options:

```
networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

and replace "Wi-Fi" with the appropriate device.

Comment: I am using Wi-Fi and I ran that command.  I am still getting the same error, even after re-starting.

Comment: This is the only solution that seems to work for me, using Yosemite + accessing a Rails web app from an Android mobie. And here is the only place I've seen this suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a mac, but that seems to be the server not accepting connections, if that is the case, it's only accepting localhost connections, try binding de server to accept all connections or bind it to 0.0.0.0 ip

Comment: There most be a config on your server, something like webrick's `-b` flag, which server are you using?

Comment: I am using both webrick and grunt-serve.  Same error message trying to hit either one.

Comment: you can start webrick issuing `rails server -b 0.0.0.0` to listen to all incomming requests

Comment: this was the only answer that worked for me. `rails server -b 0.0.0.0` now allows me to test using a mobile device

Answer (score 0):

Can you access that IP from Browser? are you sure your IP is in the same range with 192.168.0.4? It is your mobile device connected on the same network? Maybe you used internet sharing before update to Yosemite and now is off?

Comment: No, I can only run the app in my browser with http://localhost:3000.  It does not work if I try http://192.168.0.4:3000.  Even from the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think your IP address changed. Telnet from console(terminal) your I.P. port. If 192.168.0.4 is your real Ip then maybe add(as root or via sudo) an entry in /etc/host file an entry as 127.0.0.1 192.168.0.4. Restart network or reboot. Also you can try nmap (  on ip to see open ports). Nmap has been ported to OSX just google for installer.